# Flutter/Dart - Why does DateTime.toLocal() behave differently for dates before 01.01.1970 UTC aka UNIX timestamp 0?

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart, timezone, unix-timestamp

Using `.toLocal()` on `DateTime`s before 01.01.1970 (thus with a negative UNIX timestamp) seemingly results in the timezone information getting lost.

```
final DateTime date1 = DateTime.parse('1970-01-01T00:59:59.999+01:00');
final DateTime date2 = DateTime.parse('1970-01-01T01:00:00.000+01:00');
final DateTime date3 = DateTime.parse('1970-01-01T01:00:00.001+01:00');

// executing the following lines on a machine with timezone UTC+01:00

print(date1.toLocal().toIso8601String());
// expected: 1970-01-01T00:59:59.999
// actual:   1969-12-31T23:59:59.999

print(date2.toLocal().toIso8601String());
// expected: 1970-01-01T01:00:00.000
// actual:   1970-01-01T01:00:00.000

print(date3.toLocal().toIso8601String());
// expected: 1970-01-01T01:00:00.001
// actual:   1970-01-01T01:00:00.001
```

Is this a bug or intended behavior? And if the latter, how would I preserve the timezone for DateTimes older than 01.01.1970?

Info:
OS: Windows 10 Pro x64

```
$ flutter --version
Flutter 1.22.5 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 7891006299 (5 weeks ago) • 2020-12-10 11:54:40 -0800
Engine • revision ae90085a84
Tools • Dart 2.10.4
```

Note:
This issue does not seem to occur on dartpad.dev (Based on Flutter 1.25.0-8.2.pre Dart SDK 2.10.4)

UPDATE:

I filed an issue in the Dart SDK repository:
https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/44656

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint `tzutil /g` gives me `W. Europe Standard Time`.

Comment: Imo this looks like intended output. You should be careful using Flutter with anything related to a different time zone compared to local, because the internal data structure is missing the required fields to correctly convert times. There are external packages, that might help you out.

Comment: It's not the intended output.  I've been able to reproduce this, and it seems like a bug to me.  The time zone isn't relevant - anything before `1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z` causes `toLocal` to return the UTC date and time and *not* perform any local time conversion.  I recommend filing a bug [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues).